# PHP replace opening div or span by class

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

Using something like PHP's str_replace, preg_replace, or something else, I need to find all opening div or spans in a very long string that contain a certain class and replace the entire opening div or span with some other text.  For example:

If I have the following div in my string:

```
...lots of text <div style="display: inline;" class="MyClass">zoom</div> other text...
```

I want to find that div by the class name in the entire string and replace that div with "blah blah blah."  I can find the closing tag easily so I'm not worried about that one.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not using html dom parser to do it.

Comment: @Simon I didn't know there was such a thing.  I did some research, tried it out, and could not get it to work for me.  Thanks for the information though.  I'll have to take some more time to learn this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This replaces all the text between "MyClass" div tags and stores the new HTML in $string.

```
   <?php

$string = '<div class="MyClass">Change this text.</div><br /><div class="MyClass">and this text too</div>';
$pattern = "|(?<=<div class=\"MyClass\">)(.*?)(?=<\/div>)|";
$replace = 'blah blah blah';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {
    $string = str_replace($value, $replace, $string);
}

echo $string; // <div class="MyClass">blah blah blah</div><br /><div class="MyClass">blah blah blah</div>

?>
```

To replace everything including the div tags, the regex pattern would be `$pattern = "|(<div class=\"MyClass\">.*?<\/div>)|";`

Answer (score 1):

Try using a tool like phpQuery to select the elements you want and then manipulate them.

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Doing this with regular expressions would be unnecessarily painful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DOMDocument. Using regular expression will over complicate things. See my sample code below on how you would accomplish this.

```
<?php
// This is our HTML
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
    <body>
        ...lots of text <div style="display: inline;" class="MyClass">zoom</div> other text...
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

// This is the replacement.
$replacement = <<<HTML
    Blah blah blah
HTML;

// Create a new DOMDocument with our HTML.
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadHtml($html);

// Create a new DOMDocument with the replacement text.
$replacementDocument = new DOMDocument;
$replacementDocument->loadXml('<root>' . $replacement . '</root>');
// Import the nodes from the replacement document into the existing document.
$newNodes = array();
foreach($replacementDocument->firstChild->childNodes as $childNode){
    $newNodes[] = $document->importNode($childNode,true);
}
// Create an xpath use for querying.
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// Find all nodes that have a class with "MyClass"
foreach($xpath->query('//*[contains(@class,\'MyClass\')]') as $element){
    // Remove all the nodes inside this node.
    foreach($element->childNodes as $childNode){
        $element->removeChild($childNode);
    }
    // All all the new nodes.
    foreach($newNodes as $newNode){
        $element->appendChild($newNode);
    }
}
// Echo the new HTML
echo $document->saveHtml();
?>
```